# Erro ao capturar informação de componente no Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Meus amigos, estou começando a estudar angular, estou fazendo um CRUD de produtos me deparei com o seguinte erro ao criar o componente para editar o produto cadastrado.
Tentei de varias formas, mas nada resolveu.
Aparece as seguintes mensagens:

"*error TS2564: Property 'product' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
13   product: Product*"

e

"*error TS2663: Cannot find name 'product'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.product'?
20       this.product = product*"

Esse é meu arquivo product-update.component.html ele é que deveria mostrar o produto que será editado.

```
    <mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Alterar Produto</mat-card-title>
    <form>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Nome"
                [(ngModel)]="product.name" name="name">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Preço (R$)"
                [(ngModel)]="product.price" name="price">
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="updateProduct()" color="primary">
        Atualizar
    </button>
    
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="cancel()">
        Cancelar
    </button>
</mat-card>
```

E este é o meu product-update.component.ts que deveria ser o responsável por trazer as informações do produto selecionado. Ainda não terminei todas as funções desse arquivo. As mensagens de erro aparecem nele.

    `import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-update',
  templateUrl: './product-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-update.component.css']
})
export class ProductUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  
  product: Product

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || ''
    this.productService.readById(id).subscribe(prduct => {
      this.product = product
      
    });
  }

  updateProduct():void{

  }

  cancel(): void{
    this.router.navigate(['/products'])
  }

}`

Eu preciso identificar como corrigir estas duas mensagens de erro, se algum puder ajudar, agradeço imensamente.

Comment: acho que inves de só declarar o product vc tem que inicializar ele como um produto vazio

Comment: Se eu fizer isso, vai trazer no HTML os campos vazios, mas eu preciso que traga as informações do produto relacionado ao ID para poder editar. ou não?

Comment: vc pode fazer um ngif="product" no html tbm ali na altura do form

Comment: Não está faltando instanciar o **Product** não??!

Comment: Você deveria inicializar o proudct = new Product(); E no momento que você faz o "readById" você escreveu 'prduct' ao invés de 'product'

Comment: Quando você criar o **Product**, tente fazer assim: `product!: Product` .  Acredito que isso deva resolver.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso

```
export class ProductUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  product!: Product;

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    this.productService.readById(id).subscribe(product => {
      this.product = product;

    })

  }
```

No product.service

tente isso

```
readById(id: any): Observable<Product>{
    const url= `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`
    return this.http.get<Product>(url)
  }
```